# Register Doctrine2 entity listener as service in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

For the context, I use Symfony 2.4 & Doctrine 2.4.

I'm currently trying to move some logic inside doctrine entity listeners. For now, I have just used the `@EntityListeners` annotation in order to register my listeners on my entities as it does not need external dependencies. But now, I would like to inject services into my entity listeners though the Symfony2 container. As this feature is quite new, there is not related doc explaining if it is first possible & second, how it can be done.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but can't find any info about Doctrine version 2.4. Does it exist?

Comment: Doctrine 2.4 has been released one month ago. See https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/releases Anyway, what I ask is not supported. I have opened a ticket on the bug tracker: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/223 which explains my workaround (a possible solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the [Symfony docs on Entity Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html) to find out how to register entity listeners as a service:

```yaml
services:
    user_listener:
        class: \UserListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity_manager: custom }
```

Comment: Nice to see it has been added to doctrine natively :)

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in Doctrine 2.4 but requires you to create your own Entity Listener Resolver class.

See [Doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners-resolver) for details on registering a custom resolver which takes a container (or ServiceManager in my case) as a constructor param.

I have not tried this with the Symfony2 container but I have with Zend Framework 2's [ServiceManager module](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html) and the principles are likely to be extremely similar.

ZF2's DoctrineORMModule makes this whole process very elegant by using the ServiceManager to call MyEntityListenerResolverFactory which in turn injects the ServiceManager into the MyEntityListenerResolver.